# How can I keep my keyboard's lights on on startup?

Tags: scripts, keyboard, 22.04, startup

I've created the following `/etc/rc.local` file in order to turn on the lights of my keyboard on startup :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
scrolllock=$(ls /sys/class/leds/ | grep scrolllock)
echo 1 | tee /sys/class/leds/$scrolllock/brightness
exit 0
```

It works briefly, but as soon as the login screen appears, the lights turn off.

After login, I must open the console, type `sudo /etc/rc.local` and type my password to light up my keyboard.

What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: when the login screen apppears, ubuntu tries to save some power. keeping it on while not using it will drain 20%+ more battery within some time frame(lets say 30 minutes).

Comment: Ubuntu is on my desktop, the keyboard is plugged in a usb port, there is no battery involved

Comment: But i wouldn't recommend doing it, since it takes more of your electricity bill. It's best to keep it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Num Lock** and **Scroll Lock** in *BIOS Menu*.

Comment: That's not what I want, I am fine with the Scroll Lock